# solving triangle line measurements

Tags: geometry

How to solve given a triangle with side measurements of 36, 39, and 59. Need to know what the inside angle is between the line measures of 36 and 59. This is not a right triangle.

Comment: Law of cosines.

Comment: @rogerl:  I thought so too -- but that's not a geometry tool.  If it had been tagged "trigonometry"...

Comment: @EricTowers Picky, picky :)

Comment: @rogerl:  It may well be mis-tagged, but I don't have any way to know that until noah gives us more hints.

Comment: sorry, Law of Cosines sounds right. What else do I need to put in?

Answer (score 0):

if $\theta$ is the angle, $b$ and $c$ are two lengths (36 and 59) and $a$ the length opposite $\theta$ (39)

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{36^2+59^2-39^2}{2\times36\times59}$$

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{407}{531}$$

$$\therefore \quad \theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{407}{531}\right)\approx 0.697$$

a geometric proof of the cos rule can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines#Using_geometry_of_the_circle

Comment: In what way is this geometry?

Comment: @EricTowers In the above answer, a link has been provided showing how the law of cosines is developed (by various methods, including geometrical method). If you like, you can start your question with the numerical data given, and go through the same old road as the proof to obtaining the expected answer (geometrically). Sometimes, solving some particular problems purely in geometric manner may not be possible. At the most we can only cut the involvement of trigonometric skills to a minimum.

Comment: I added the link after he'd written that
(as we'd been asked for it geometrically, he was quite right to call me out on it)